# DialogFlow CX inline system functions not working

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am trying to use system function for dynamic response but its not working.

```
$sys.func.IF("$session.params.firstname = null", "admin", $session.params.firstname)
```

Here in both the case i am getting same response. If session param is null than it is not working.

Is there any other approach to solve this.

I tried condition response but not worked.

Comment: There seems to be no problem with the system function. Please explain how you did the flow design.